# Cравнение пикселей по цвету в разное время, в одной точке на python

Tags: python, numpy

мне нужно написать код на Python где при смене пикселей делается скрин и отправляется мне в ЛС. Нужно часть сравнения.
код:

```
from mss import *
import telebot
import numpy as np
from time import *

# Проба цвета с координ
x=886
y=395
m = mss()
monitor = {
    "left": x,
    "top": y,
    "width": 1,
    "height": 1,
}
# Получаем пиксель с экрана монитора
im = m.grab(monitor)
# Преобразуем этот пиксель в матрицу
im_arr = np.array(im)

  #Проба цвета с координат

monito = {
    "left": x,
    "top": y,
    "width": 1,
    "height": 1,
}
# Получаем пиксель с экрана монитора
img = m.grab(monito)
# Преобразуем этот пиксель в матрицу
img_arr = np.array(img)
    
print(im_arr)
sleep(5)
print(img_arr)
if np.array_equal(im_arr, img_arr):
    print(1)
else:
    print(0)
```

Но ошибка:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Помогите пж.

Comment: ну и поставьте all, вам же нужно, чтобы все были равны. или any если сравниваете на неравенство

Comment: Код лучше добавьте прямо в вопрос, благо он у вас небольшой.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте функцию [numpy.array_equal](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array_equal.html) для сравнения двух массивов `Numpy`:

```
if np.array_equal(im_arr, img_arr):
```

Хотя, если у вас ровно один пиксел, то можно взять первое (и единственное) значение из каждого массива и сравнивать его:

```
if im_arr[0] == img_arr[0]:
```

Comment: Но теперь всегда выдаёт один и тот же цвет даже если он реально меняется, соотвецтвенно печатает 1

Comment: @Иван А вы пробовали печатать содержимое `im_arr` и `img_arr` перед этим сравнением? Что выдаёт `print(im_arr, img_arr)`?

Comment: Нет, я печатаю im_arr потом слип так как нужно не в ту же секунду проверять иначе даже при смене картинки оно будет одинаковое, img_arr

Comment: ну и вообще не обязательно через нампи можно вроде через ОpenCV ну как легче будет для вас

Comment: @Иван Добавьте код в вопрос не ссылкой, а прямо текстом для начала. Не каждый будет ходить по ссылке и мне тоже неудобно по ссылке смотреть вспоминать ваш код

Comment: Cделано, да и почему np.array_equal(im_arr,img_arr) Всегда выдает одинаковый цвет хотя на самом деле он рпзный

Comment: Вы уверены, что пиксел разный? Что print печатает обоих массивов?

Comment: Координаты одни, но мне нужно чтобы оно проверялось например каждую секунду сначала 1 а потом вторым массивом и если они не совпадают то делать скрин, и я полностью уверен что цвета разные но выводит один и тотже